# How do I get the classic windows dropdown buttons in winforms/visual studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

I was looking for the classic windows-esque menu buttons that look like this and are abundant in nearly every windows application before windows 8:
[image]

I can't find them in winforms though. The closest thing I could find was the MenuStrip control, which doesn't looK like this. Are there any things I could do to get these buttons back?

Comment: Yep, that's a MenuStrip. When you add some ToolStripMenuItems, it will look exactly like that. You can use the Designer to add Items / SubItems.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to get those dark grey seperators?

Comment: Like the one between "What's This?" and "About Phone Dialer" @Jimi

Comment: You can simply type a dash in as the text and that will create a separator automatically.

Comment: That's a `System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator` object. You can still add it using the Designer. Did you add a MenuStrip to the Form and at least one ToolStripMenuItem to it? The sub-items ComboBox selector also shows the Separator object. Or you can add it in code.

Comment: That's the old [MainMenu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mainmenu?view=netframework-4.8). component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a MenuStrip to your form:

[image]

After adding a MenuItem you can add Separators (as well as other things)

[image]